# Django How to preload Fat Class

Tags: django, tensorflow, nginx, uwsgi

How can I use Django preload this fat class?

because when requests come in My code will do like:

```
MyFatClass()
```

then it's very slow to loading this class

have any idea to preload this class in global and very django requests comes will take already preload's fat class?

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
         if cls not in cls._instances:cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
         return cls._instances[cls]

class MyFatClass(metaclass=Singleton):
      # something about tensorflow
```

---

Now,  I put it under the "manage.py"

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    MyFatClass()
```

then I works.

but I think that is a little bit hackish

Comment: If in any of the files that are automatically imported when Django is started (e.g .your models.py) you create an instance of your class (`fat = MyFatClass()`) and then import that instance when you need it, it'll already be in memory.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks let me try it :D

Comment: You could also add it to `settings`, but that feels a bit hackish.

Comment: @FlipperPA I can't agree with you more XD